# TextEditor component is marked secure='true' but the HTML Sanitizer was not found on the classpath

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Error message:

TextEditor component is marked secure='true' but the HTML Sanitizer was not found on the classpath. Either add the HTML sanitizer to the classpath per the documentation or mark secure='false' if you would like to use the component without the sanitizer.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.jsf</groupId>
    <artifactId>showcase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <name>showcase</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

textEditor.xhtml:

```
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="primeicons/primeicons.css" library="primefaces"/>
    </h:head>
    
    <h:body>
        <h:form>    
            <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
            <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" value="#{editorView.text}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>
             
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="pi pi-save" />
            <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor1').clear();" icon="pi pi-times" />
             
            <h3 class="first">Custom Toolbar</h3>
            <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor2" value="#{editorView.text2}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px" placeholder="Enter your content">
                <f:facet name="toolbar">
                     <span class="ql-formats">
                        <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                        <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                        <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                        <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ql-formats">
                        <select class="ql-font"></select>
                        <select class="ql-size"></select>
                    </span>
                </f:facet>
            </p:textEditor>
             
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="pi pi-save" />
            <p:commandButton value="Clear" type="button" onclick="PF('editor2').clear();" icon="pi pi-times" />
             
            <p:dialog header="Content" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                <p:outputPanel id="display">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
                    <h:outputText value="#{editorView.text}" escape="false" />
         
                    <h3>Custom</h3>
                    <h:outputText value="#{editorView.text2}" escape="false" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>     
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

EditorView.java

```
package com.jsf.showcase.view.input;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EditorView {
    private String text;
    private String text2;
}
```

PrimeFaces version: 8

Comment: So you added it to the classpath and it worked?

Comment: I don't know how to edit and add it.

Comment: there is a duplicate about this in Stackoverflow iirc. And this also is in the PF docs

Answer (score 6):

I have solved with this dependency. Thanks Kukeltje.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
    <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
    <version>20191001.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to Mario's answer, that dependency is not available today. I used the following dependency and it also works fine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>html-types</artifactId>
        <version>20200713.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the `textEditor` element has the `secure`    attribute on `true` by default. This is because we need the text editor to be protected against XSS attacks (you wouldn't want an attacker to write malicious code in your editor, that can then be executed in other user's browsers)

https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/

Hence why you need to not only use the dependency owasp-java-html-sanitizer but to keep it up to date in case vulnerabilities in it appear.

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer